# Anybody know how to solve a "viewDidUnload undeclared" problem?

Tags: iphone, xcode, undeclared-identifier

And also how to solve an "expected ';' before '{' token? code below (from xcode 3.2.3)

```
- (void)viewDidUnload {

    self.cheatName = nil;

    self.description = nil;

}
```

Both errors are in the first line

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.titleLabel setText:self.title];
    [self.descriptionLabel setText:self.description];


    float textHeight = [MLUtils calculateHeightOfTextFromWidth:self.description : descriptionLabel.font :descriptionLabel.frame.size.width :UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    CGRect frame = descriptionLabel.frame;
    frame.size.height = textHeight;
    descriptionLabel.frame = frame;

    CGSize contentSize = descriptionScrollView.contentSize;
    contentSize.height = textHeight;
    descriptionScrollView.contentSize = contentSize;



- (void)viewDidUnload {
    self.cheatName = nil;
    self.description = nil;

}
```

Comment: What is the code above the code you posted?

Answer (score 6):

Your are missing a closing bracket:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.titleLabel setText:self.title];
    [self.descriptionLabel setText:self.description];


    float textHeight = [MLUtils calculateHeightOfTextFromWidth:self.description : descriptionLabel.font :descriptionLabel.frame.size.width :UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    CGRect frame = descriptionLabel.frame;
    frame.size.height = textHeight;
    descriptionLabel.frame = frame;

    CGSize contentSize = descriptionScrollView.contentSize;
    contentSize.height = textHeight;
    descriptionScrollView.contentSize = contentSize;

} // <-- HERE

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    self.cheatName = nil;
    self.description = nil;

}
```

---

Second, I am not sure whether this line is valid:

```
float textHeight = [MLUtils calculateHeightOfTextFromWidth:self.description : descriptionLabel.font :descriptionLabel.frame.size.width :UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
```

I think you have to add the parameter names like (fictive names!):

```
float textHeight = [MLUtils calculateHeightOfTextFromWidth:self.description font: descriptionLabel.font width:descriptionLabel.frame.size.width whatever:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
```

Comment: Then I get an error later down the line:

- (void)viewDidUnload {
 self.cheatName = nil;
 self.description = nil;
 
}
 

 
 - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
 // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
 
 // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}




 - (void)dealloc {
 [titleLabel release];
 [descriptionLabel release];
 [descriptionScrollView release];
 [cheatName release];
 [description release];
    [super dealloc];
}

}
@end

Comment: the error is at the two brackets at the end - it says I need a "(" before "}" token

If I remove it, then there are a whole load more errors that have no meaning to the project (like 35 or so)

Comment: @nolimitsplayer: It is hard to tell without the the whole code. I suggest to go through your code, fold the methods and see if the folding is done correctly. Verify that the number of opening and closing brackets are the same, etc.

Comment: Can I upload the file to you?

Comment: Wait no it is like 65MB for a simple application (WTF)

I don't know what to do. All of the brackets are where they should be, etc.

What can I do? I don't feel like fixing all of it over again.

Comment: The syntax `[o foo:a :b :c]` is actually valid, but it refers to the selector `foo:::` instead of `foo:bar:baz:`.

Comment: What does that mean?

I'm pretty much done with the project. (Unless someone wants to work on it with me)

Comment: http://pastebin.com/g0sBYD2J

The double brackets right before the viewdidunload thing is where the trouble is.

Comment: @nolimitsplayer: Now you have two brackets, in line 27 and 28. Remove one.

Comment: If I do there is a massive error breaking out, with referencing weird files:

http://imgur.com/5c3tQ.png

Answer (score 0):

usually that means that you have an error somewhere above that line. Or misplaced { }.